# Lexical or Preprocessor issue. - "File not found."

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

Every time I update my cocoapods using `cocoa update` command I get this error.

> Lexical or Preprocessor issue. - "File not found."

Actually I'm having 7 targets in one project. So on updating the pods my base target that I created while creating the project works fine. But while running other 6 targets I get the error in which those targets are not able to found any of the pods file.

Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You to share pods among multiple targets you could use abstract_target

```
abstract_target 'BaseTarget' do
    //Specify your pods
    # Specify your actual targets
    target 'Target1'
    target 'Target2'
end
```

Please not that `BaseTarget` is just an identifier and not the name of any actual targets in your project.

Comment: [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] The specification of `link_with` in the Podfile is now unsupported, please use target blocks instead..

Comment: I'm getting the above error after adding the mentioned command in pod file.

Comment: @RohitaxRajguru I have updated the answer please check.